# How to dynamically change Javascript Height

Tags: javascript, dynamic, height

I know that this question has been asked a lot and I assure you I have read a majority of the answers.  However, in my case, none of it has worked for me.  I am currently trying this:

```js
window.onload = function(){

    var winWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
    var winHeight = parseInt(window.innerHeight);

    document.getElementById("copyRight").innerHTML = winHeight;
    //This is so I could make sure the height was actually changing. It is.

    document.getElementById("grandeContain").style.width = winWidth-15+"px";
    document.getElementById("grandeContain").style.height = winheight+"px";
    document.getElementById("contain").style.width = winWidth-105+"px";
    document.getElementById("contain").style.height = winHeight-90+"px";
    document.getElementById("outside").style.width = winWidth-105+"px";
    document.getElementById("outside").style.height = winHeight-90+"px";
    document.getElementById("aroundToolBar").style.height = winHeight-90+"px";
}
```

However, no matter what I do the height is not changing `onload` (I also have this copy and pasted into an `onresize` function and that doesn't work either). The width parts work fine (not just because that is the default setting for divs; I've tested with many different widths based on `window.innerWidth` and it changed) but the heights refuses to change.  What am I doing wrong? I've always had trouble dynamically changing height and it would be great if I could figure this out once and for all.

Also, if css has anything to do with it, the div tree is like this: `grandeContain>contain>(aroundToolBar+outside)` where `contain` is `position:relative`, `aroundToolbar` is `float:left` and `width:125px`, and `outside` is `position:relative` with `margin 0 0 0 125px`.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Also, the 105s and 90s are there soley because of a header and footer in the `grandeContain` div, with their sibling contain.

Comment: So, do you get any exceptions? Or could you make a demo?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in firebug for errors? it seems like on the line:

```
document.getElementById("grandeContain").style.height = winheight+"px";
```

you have a typo: should be `winHeight+"px"` instead of `winheight+"px"`; maybe causing a variable undefined error.